# Determining the probability of the square of a sum of 3 normal variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $\bar{X}$ is distributed $N_3(\bar{0}, \bar{\Sigma})$, where:

$\bar{\Sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

Find $P((X_1 - 2X_2 + X_3)^2 > 15.36)$.

My first idea was to square root both sides and split into disjoint cases $P(X_1 - 2X_2 + X_3 > \sqrt{15.36})$ and $P(X_1 - 2X_2 + X_3 < -\sqrt{15.35})$.

Then I wanted to write $Y = X_1 - 2X_2 + X_3$ and find the distribution of $Y$.

However, because the $X_i$ are not independent (they are correlated), I cannot conclude that $Y$ is normal. So now I am a bit stuck.

My second idea was to perform some transformation of $\bar{X}$ into some random vector of uncorrelated (hence independent) normal random variables (e.g. $\bar{Z} \sim N_3(\bar{0}, I_3)$ where $I_3$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix).

According to my text, if $\bar{Y} = \bar{A} \bar{X} + \bar{b}$ for some $3 \times 3$ matrix $\bar{A}$ and $3 \times 1$ vector $\bar{b}$, then $Y$ has $N_3(\bar{b}, \bar{A} \bar{\Sigma} \bar{A}')$ distribution. So ideally I would find some $\bar{A}$ such that $\bar{A} \bar{\Sigma} \bar{A}' = I_3$. But this is also proving to be difficult.

Even if I were to find such a transformation, I'm not sure where I would proceed from here (how is the transformed random vector related to the probability statement about the $X_i$'s?)

Does anyone have any ideas? My text (Hogg Introduction to Mathematical Statistics 7th ed.) is not offering much in the way of hints or examples.

Comment: $Y$ is normal; it is the projection of a gaussian vector onto $\mathbb R$. This is the definition of a gaussian vector, in fact. $X$ is a gaussian vector if and only if $c^T X$ is gaussian for all $c$

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure I understand - I thought we could only say a linear combination of normal random variables was normal if those random variables were independent?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent gaussian. Then $Z = X+(X-Y)$ is, by your logic, simultaneously gaussian and not gaussian. Indeed, $X$ and $X-Y$ are not independent, so $Z$ is not gaussian. On the other hand, $Z = 2X-Y$, the sum of independent gaussians.

Comment: @Andrew I understand. Then how can I find the mean and variance of $Y = X_1 - 2X_2 + X_3$? If the $X_i$ were independent we'd have $Y \sim N(\mu_1 - 2\mu_2 + \mu_3, \sigma_1^2 + 4 \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_3^2)$, but I haven't seen a formula for when they're dependent.

Comment: A gaussian is completely determined by its first two moments. It is an easy exercise to show $$\mathrm{Var}\left(\sum_{1}^n X_i\right) = \sum_i^n \mathrm{Var}(X_i)-2\sum_{i<j}\mathrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$$

Comment: @Andrew I was able to derive this and obtain the right answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find this answer thanks to the comments of user @Andrew:

Write $Y = \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i X_i$, where $a_1 = a_3 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$.

It is easy to show in general that:

$E[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i E[X_i]$

and

$Var[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i^2 Var[X_i] + 2 \sum_{i<j} a_i a_j Cov(X_i, X_j)$

In our case:

$Var[Y] = 1^2 Var[X_1] + (-2)^2 Var[X_2] + 1^2 Var[X_3] + 2(1)(-2) Cov(X_1, X_2) + 2(1)(1) Cov(X_1, X_3) + 2(-2)(1) Cov(X_2, X_3)$

Plugging in the terms of the matrix:

$Var[Y] = 3 + 4 \times 2 + 3 - 4 \times 2 + 2 \times 1 - 4 \times 1$

$ \implies Var[Y] = 4$

Furthermore each $X_i$ has mean $0$, and so we have that $Y \sim N(0, 4)$.

The original problem reduces to:

$P(Y^2 > 15.36) = P(Y < -\sqrt{15.36}) + P(Y > \sqrt{15.36})$

$= 1 - P(Y < \sqrt{15.36}) + 1 - P(Y < \sqrt{15.35})$

$ = 2 - 2P(Y < \sqrt{15.36})$

$= 2(1 - P(Z < \frac{\sqrt{15.36}}{2} )) = 0.05$

where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Consulting a normal distribution table provides us the final answer.